# Change in a list in Python when it is called recursively

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I was solving some problems on a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and I got stuck in the question *[Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary Tree | Set 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-binary-tree-set-1/)*.

I am using Python to solve the question.

My question is like in the case where we want to find the common ancestor between 4 and 5, how when the function is called first time [1,2,4] is returned...

How.... shouldn't 3, 6, 7 be also be appended in the list along with 1,2,4 when (root.right!= None and findPath(root.right, path, k) is called recursively.

PS: Please refer to the Python code given in the link

Comment: The question part is close to incomprehensible. Are you using machine translation, e.g. [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)? Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67957515/edit)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're asking about appears to be the `findPath` function, copied here:

```
# Finds the path from root node to given root of the tree.
# Stores the path in a list path[], returns true if path
# exists otherwise false
def findPath( root, path, k):
 
    # Baes Case
    if root is None:
        return False
 
    # Store this node is path vector. The node will be
    # removed if not in path from root to k
    path.append(root.key)
 
    # See if the k is same as root's key
    if root.key == k :
        return True
 
    # Check if k is found in left or right sub-tree
    if ((root.left != None and findPath(root.left, path, k)) or
            (root.right!= None and findPath(root.right, path, k))):
        return True
 
    # If not present in subtree rooted with root, remove
    # root from path and return False
      
    path.pop()
    return False
```

(Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-binary-tree-set-1/)

And you're confused about how the `path` output argument works. That's a fair question, as the algorithm is a little indirect about how it builds that list.

Let's look at all of the return codepaths, and specifically focus on what's happening to `path` when this happens. I've copied the above code without the comments, focusing just on the main logic of the function. The comments are mine. I've also renamed "`root`" to "`current`" as this makes the method more clear.

```
def findPath(current, path, k):
 
    # Put the current node's key at the end of the path list.
    path.append(current.key)
 
    # Return immediately if the current node is the target.
    if current.key == k:
        return True
 
    # Return immediately if one of the current node's children contains the target.
    if ((current.left != None and findPath(current.left, path, k)) or
            (current.right!= None and findPath(current.right, path, k))):
        return True
 
    # Remove the current node's key from the path list.
    path.pop()
    return False
```

So, we can think of this function as essentially doing the following (in pseudocode):

```
def findPath(current, path, target):
  path += current.key
  if (current or its children contain target):
    return True
  else 
    path -= current.key
    return False
```

Note that only in the "happy" case, where current or its children contain target, do we leave `current.key` in `path`. In all other code paths, we remove `current.key` from `path`. So, in the end, `path` will contain exactly the keys between `root` and `target`.

Comment: thank yo so much i understood this now i have one more question .....what would have happened if there was no path.pop method what list would have returned....What i am trying to ask is What happens to a list if it is called recursively by 2 functions what list will be retruned

Comment: It would be a pre-order traversal of the tree.

Comment: how,,, can you please elaborate?What will be inside the list if it is changed recursively by two functions

Comment: After one call, the list would contain the pre-order traversal of the tree, truncated at the target value, since the algorithm stops traversing once it reaches the target. Calling it a second time with the same list would yield that same pattern twice.